# Unity USB Thrustmaster Joystick

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, joystick

I am trying to use a USB Joystick in Unity.
I am working with Unity 5.5.1 on a Windows 10 PC. The Joystick works perfectly on my machine.
But in Unity, the joystick gives me some weird axis outputs.

I tried to map my joystick input with the Unity Input Manager. But it doesn't work at all.
On the horizontal axis I get values from -1 to -0.6(center) to 0 to +0.6 instead of just -1 to 0(center) to 1.

Another weird thing is, that everything works just fine on my macbook. Is this a windows issue?

Did somebody else had this problem before?

Comment: try using latest or more recent version of unity, if it's still buggy I think you should report a bug

Comment: also, try a different joystick

Comment: Hi Nika, thank's for the reply. 
Did you use a joystick before in unity? Did it work ?

Comment: yes and I've never had a similar problem. On windows I'd make sure that the joystick is calibrated correctly but I don't know how it is on mac :))

Answer (score 0):

I have a torrid joystick that works perfectly everywhere except unity. I've solved my issue with input.getaxis().. not being 0 by watching what was the value when the controller was set in neutral position(0.14f) and when it was set on maximum position(1.14f), and with a simple modification to the script that said something like this input.getaxis()-0.14f I've solved my problem. however, I would not recommend doing that if you are going to publish your project because that offset will be different for every user, so I would suggest writing a calibration tool that would take the offset and implement in everywhere in the game for that specific user